# Where in the Torah does it say we are the Temple of Hashem?

Tags: talmud-gemara

The Talmud and Kabbalah speak of man being the Temple of Hashem, but where can we find that in the Torah?

Comment: Do you know where in Talmud it speaks of that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please see Vaikra 15:31 and Bemidbar 19:13. It is being implied there.

31 Thus shall ye separate the children of Israel from their uncleanness; that they die not in their uncleanness, when they defile My tabernacle that is in the midst of them.

13 Whosoever toucheth the dead, even the body of any man that is dead, and purifieth not himself--he hath defiled the tabernacle of the LORD--that soul shall be cut off from Israel; because the water of sprinkling was not dashed against him, he shall be unclean; his uncleanness is yet upon him.

Comment: [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9916#showrashi=true) says
"The punishment כָּרֵת the death of the perpetrator and his offspring-is attached to an unclean person who enters the sanctuary, thus defiling it" which does not support your answer. Do you have a source for your answer?

Comment: re: my previous comment - Rashi to Vayikro 15 (31).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok What are you talking about? I think the verses I cited are self-explanatory. What source do you want? I am giving you Torah. That is the best source there is afaik.